# Can't view an image in table cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

guys

I'm doing [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells) tutorial but after writing the code I can't see any images in the table cells -> they're white!

I added the picture files in the Supporting Files folder, read the tutorial one more time, but can't solve this problem! Please, can anyone help me with this?

```
@interface CarTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation CarTableViewController

@synthesize  carMakes = _carMakes;
@synthesize carImages = _carImages;
@synthesize carModels = _carModels;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Chevy", @"BMW", @"Toyota", @"Volvo", @"Smart", nil];
    self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Volt", @"Mini", @"Venza", @"S60", @"Fortwo", nil];
    self.carImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"chevy_volt.jpg", @"mini_clubman.jpg", @"toyota_venza.jpg", @"volvo_s60.jpg", @"smart_fortwo.jpg", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.carModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
        cell.makeLabel.text = [self.carMakes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.modelLabel.text = [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.carImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
        cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check name is same as you add in Supporting Files folder

Comment: Did you set the imageView IBOutletConnection ?

Comment: There is no problem regarding coding as per the tutorial. Please make sure that you are connecting the IBOutletConnections properly to the CustomCell not to the FilesOwner

Comment: your code is nop... but see IBOutlet connections like ....... dont follow "Sync"  calling ,  please try to call "Asyc" calling..... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @Nims the names are identical

Comment: @Manohar the connetction is carImage - Car Table View Cell

Comment: then add your images in Targets>Build Phase>Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: you are able to see everything except images rite ??

Comment: that both methods are called?? i.e have u set table view delegate or not??....or everthing is going correct only ypu can not see images is problem???

Comment: Did you copy all the images which you have downloaded from link to your project.

Comment: @Nims OK now, I added the images in the project folder and from this place import them in xcode -> so now I can see them in the simulator, but what's wrong with them now? see screenshot here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15833199/1.png

Comment: now what problem you have??

Comment: hey cell.carImage.image size is to big then cell height.Plz make it proper..Put this method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @Nims Can u please give me the code of this method applied to the app, can't understand how it can help me to make the proper height. And it's strange that there is nothing about it in the tutorial( Thank u in advance!

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{Return 80;} Use this Delegate Event you give height of the cell. and also cell.carImage..frame = CGRectMakeCGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height) you give frame for image

Comment: @Nims 'cell.carImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 41, 60, 38);' add this but I don't think the situation is better now LOOK here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15833199/2.png

Comment: add this code - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{Return 80;}

Comment: LOOK https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15833199/3.png

Comment: I recreated the project - and the project is OK. It seems something was wrong with the xcode. Thank u, @Nims

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.carImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
cell.imgCar.image = im;
```

If still not working, then your image is not properly copied in  your project. Kindly remove and add it again.

And dont forgert to **@synthesize** your imageView

Thanks, Happy Coding..

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15833199/1.png so, the files weren't copied properly -> but now something is wrong again.. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: if we are using customCell in tableView., then we have to synthesize it in our customCell's xib.

Answer (score 0):

try settting aspect fit in xib or by following code

```
cell.imgCar.image.imageViewContentmode = UIViewContentModeAspectFit;
```